# The type or namespace name 'ILogger<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [PaymentApi]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a new web api project using this commands

```
dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi
cd TodoApi
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory --prerelease
code -r ../TodoApi
```

But all namespace are missed. How to restore those?

I have 26 errors.

Ex :

```
The name 'WebApplication' does not exist in the current context [TechnePaymentApi]
```

```
A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [TechnePaymentApi]
```

See this screenshot of errors

[image]

Updated:- problem solved

This issue is because of older version of vs code and c#.
I  updated both vs code and c# plugin in my PC. After that I created a asp .net core 6.0 project. There is no errors.

Comment: In your package, are the packages downloaded by nuget still there?

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />

Comment: @hanushic Can you delete all obj folder and rebuild your solution? It may work sometime. Also, update all nuget packages if there is any update

Comment: Have you updated VS Code and especially C#  extension to the latest version?